# Console output not displaying correctly in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm writing a fraction class for this school assignment and am having trouble getting the console message to display before the input. The cout line should display before reading the input from the console, however it only shows up after I have already typed an input into the console. I'm new to Qt, so I'm not familiar with how it works under the hood.

Here is the code:

```
// one of the requrements is we have to use Qt instead of the standard iostream
int main(void) {
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    QTextStream cin(stdin);

    Fraction f1, f2, add, sub, mul, div;
    QString line;

    cout << "Enter the numerator and denominator of fraction 1: ";
    line = cin.readLine();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tell it to flush the stream.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Why do I need to flush the stream though? Aren't the two streams separate from each other? I'd like to understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: `std::cin` and `std::cout` are tied, but not `stdin` and `stdout` (afaik), and definitely are not when used with `QTextStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have text actually shown, it needs to be flushed. Depending on details, flushing may be automatically done when a newline is written, and obviously at least when the application write buffer is full, and when the file is closed. In your application, none of these happen. So you must flush your `cout` manually, using [`QTextStream::flush()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#flush).

*"Aren't the two streams separate from each other?"*, exactly, they are. Your two `QTextStream` objects are completely unrelated, so you reading from *your* `cin` has no way to tell *your* `cout` to flush its buffers. Related, note that `iostreams` as well as C *stdio* stuff has special mechanism causing *stdout* to be flushed when reading from *stdin*.

As to why `QTextStream` does not flush after every `<<` operation, that's to make output more efficient. Flushing means a system call needs to be made, which are slow (compared to just copying text from one place to another inside an application).

Unrelated, I would not name your own objects `cin` and `cout`, because it is bound to cause confusion with `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Very helpful!